# Unable to find com.projectjava.demosclient.entity.Productos with id 0"

Tags: java, mysql, api, spring-boot, spring

Hola necesito ayuda con el siguiente codigo, tengo la entidad inventario de lo cual en esta entidad instancio 2 objetos o entidades, Producto y Proveedor.
Mi idea es combinar estas 2 o al menos traer los ID de cada producto y Proveedor para luego mostrar en pantalla el stock Actual del ID de cada producto y la fecha de ingreso y de egreso con su respectivo proveedor. No entiendo que es lo que le estaria haciendo falta a este codigo y por que el siguiente error:
Unable to find com.projectjava.demosclient.entity.Productos with id 0"

ENTITY INVENTARIO

```
package com.projectjava.demosclient.entity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "inventario")
public class Inventario {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

     @OneToOne(optional = false)
     @JoinColumn(name = "productos",nullable = true)
    private Productos producto;



@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "proveedor",nullable = true)
    private Proveedor proveedor;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
    private int stockActual;
    @Column(name = "fecha_ingreso")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaIngreso;


@Column(name = "fecha_egreso")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaEgreso;



public Inventario(Productos productos, Proveedor proveedores) {
    this.producto = productos;
    this.proveedor = proveedores;
    this.stockActual = 13;
    fechaIngreso = new Date(2020,Calendar.APRIL, 3);
    fechaEgreso = new Date(2021,Calendar.APRIL, 5);
}


public Inventario() {
}
// otros atributos y métodos

@PrePersist
private void prePersist(){
    fechaEgreso = new Date();
    fechaIngreso = new Date();
}




public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Productos getProducto() {
    return producto;
}

public void setProducto(Productos producto) {
    this.producto = producto;
}

public Proveedor getProveedor() {
    return proveedor;
}

public void setProveedor(Proveedor proveedor) {
    this.proveedor = proveedor;
}

public int getStockActual() {
    return stockActual;
}

public void setStockActual(int stockActual) {
    this.stockActual = stockActual;
}

public Date getFechaIngreso() {
    return fechaIngreso;
}

public void setFechaIngreso(Date fechaIngreso) {
    this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
}

public Date getFechaEgreso() {
    return fechaEgreso;
}

public void setFechaEgreso(Date fechaEgreso) {
    this.fechaEgreso = fechaEgreso;
}
```

}

**SERVICES**

```
@Service
public class InventarioServiceImpl implements InventarioService {
@Autowired
ProductoDao productoDao;
    @Autowired
ProveedorDao proveedorDao;
    @Autowired
InventarioDao inventarioDao;
@Override
public List<Inventario> listInventario(Long idProducto, Long idProveedor) {

    List<Inventario> inventarioList = new ArrayList<>();

    Productos producto = productoDao.findById(idProducto).orElse(null);
    Proveedor proveedor = proveedorDao.findById(idProveedor).orElse(null);
    Inventario inventario = new Inventario( producto, proveedor);
    inventarioList.add(inventario);

    return inventarioDao.saveAll(inventarioList);

}

public List<Inventario> findAll(){
    return inventarioDao.findAll();
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido Emilio. Estás en [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), y tu pregunta debería respetar el idioma del sitio. [Edítala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/592775/edit) y elimina los párrafos y frases en inglés.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

```
Unable to find entity with id ...
```

está relacionada a "lazy loading" cuando la relación puede no obtener valores, te sugiero eliminar `optional = false` o definir:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```